# Cookbook apt not found

Tags: ruby, vagrant, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have been trying to run my cookbooks from many hours and gone through multiple questions regarding the same but still couldn't manage to make it work.

> sudo chef-solo -c solo.rb -j node.json -o main::default;

I'm running the above command inside my `cookbooks` folder which contains other cookbooks like `apt`, `git`, etc.

And, inside `cookbooks/main/recipe/default.rb` I'm including `include_recipe "apt"`.

Every time, I run the command I get the following error:

> Cookbook apt not found. If you're loading apt from another cookbook,
>   make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata

So I added `depends "apt"` inside my `cookbooks/main/metadata.rb`. But now I'm getting this error:

> Cookbook depends on itself in cookbook apt, please remove this
>   unnecessary self-dependency

Comment: Based on [Chef's source](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/cookbook/metadata.rb#L289), it looks like you may have added a `depends "apt"` line within the `apt` cookbook itself. Could you include the `depends` directive calls within each of your `metadata.rb` files?

Comment: @vase I'm including depends "apt" in cookbooks/main/metadata.rb file whereas whereas apt cookbook has different folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second answer because this was diagnosed on Slack, the`main` cookbook had `name "apt"` in its metadata which made the error message confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information it's difficult to extrapolate where the problem may lie. Here's an example of how you should theoretically be laying out your cookbooks/files, though:

All cookbooks you're writing go in `<dir>/cookbooks/`.
All vendored cookbooks (e.g. `apt`) go in `<dir>/vendor/`.
So your structure, at a very stripped down level, might look something like this:

```
.
├── cookbooks
│   └── main
│       ├── metadata.rb
│       └── recipes
├── solo.rb
└── vendor
    └── apt
        ├── metadata.rb
        └── recipes
```

Now lets take a look at some individual files:

The default recipe of your `main` cookbook:

```
# cookbooks/main/recipes/default.rb

include_recipe 'apt'
```

And your `main` cookbook's metadata file:

```
# cookbooks/main/metadata.rb

name 'main'
...

depends 'apt'
```

Note that the `apt` cookbook resides in `vendor/`. Anything here should be from third parties and you *should not* modify.

From here, you just need to ensure your `solo.rb` properly references both cookbook directories for the [`cookbook_path`](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_solo.html) attribute:

```
# solo.rb

...
cookbook_path ['cookbooks/', 'vendor/']
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So as a somewhat unrelated answer: there is a very low chance you actually need that `apt::default` recipe. We've moved most of the stuff that cookbook in to Chef core. If you just want to run an `apt-get update`, use the `apt_update` resource.